# Waiting for DOM manipulation to finish before triggering CSS transition?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, css-transitions

I would like to:

1. Prepare for a CSS transition by first modifying the DOM (before state) e.g.
   `el.style.width = "200px"`
2. Trigger the CSS transition by again modifying the DOM (after state) e.g.
   `el.style.width = "0px"`

The problem I am seeing is that you need to wait for the first DOM manipulation (step 1) to finish before you can continue to trigger the CSS transition (step 2).

The workaround I found is to wait 100 ms in between. Seems to work on most browsers, but it would be nice if you could in fact wait for the DOM manipulation to finish before continuing.

```js
function dostuff() {

    let el = document.getElementById("widget");
    
    // before state (beginning of transition)
    // big box in lower right corner
    el.style.top = "100px"
        el.style.left = "100px"
        el.style.width = "200px"
        el.style.height = "200px"

        setTimeout(() => {
        // after stated (end of transiton)
      // small box in upper left corner
            el.style.top = "0px"
            el.style.left = "0px"
            el.style.width = "10px"
            el.style.height = "10px"
        }, 100);
  
}
```

```css
#widget {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="dostuff()">Click Me!</button>

<div id="widget">
</div>
```

JSFiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/fm59n02u/ (works with 100 ms, not working with 10 ms)

Comment: Please include your whole question (including any necessary code) **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/) The description above leaves far too much unsaid/unclear.

Comment: does this help : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event  forked fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/odxrj7bt/

Comment: To really help people help you, make your MRE **runnable** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event

> The transitionend event is fired when a CSS transition has completed. In the case where a transition is removed before completion, such as if the transition-property is removed or display is set to none, then the event will not be generated.

possible code update

```js
function dostuff() {

  let el = document.getElementById("widget");

  // before state (beginning of transition)
  // big box in lower right corner
  el.style.top = "100px"
  el.style.left = "100px"
  el.style.width = "200px"
  el.style.height = "200px"

  el.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
    el.style.top = "0px"
    el.style.left = "0px"
    el.style.width = "10px"
    el.style.height = "10px"
  });
}
```

```css
#widget {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="dostuff()">Click Me!</button>

<div id="widget">
</div>
```